# Changing TextView width in RecyclerView CardView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView made of CardView with several TextViews

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <LinearLayout
        <TextView...
        <TextView...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I'm trying to change the width of a TextView to be equal in each RecyclerView row and to fit the widest content, so it looks like a table with equal columns. To do that I made a function:

```
private fun optimizeLayout() {
    var maxWidth = 100
    val recyclerView = myRecyclerViewLayout

    recyclerView.doOnLayout {
        // Get max width
        for (i in 0 until recyclerView.childCount) {
            val v = recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(i)
            val tv = v?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDest)
            if (tv != null) {
                tv.measure(0, 0)
                if (tv.measuredWidth > maxWidth) maxWidth = tv.measuredWidth
                println(i.toString() + " " + tv.measuredWidth)
            }
        }
        // Set width
        for (i in 0 until recyclerView.childCount) {
            val v = recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(i)
            val tv = v?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDest)
            if (tv != null) {
                tv.width = maxWidth
                println("set $i")
            }
        }
        // Header width
        txtHeader.doOnLayout { txtHeader.width = maxWidth }
    }
}
```

This function was created after reading many other posts on a similar topic on the Internet. I call it from onViewCreated of the Fragment that contains the RecyclerView and it works fine beside that I get warnings:

```
requestLayout() improperly called by com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView{b1b06f0 V.ED..... ......ID 0,5-143,110 #7f0a0225 app:id/txtDest} during layout: running second layout pass
```

I also have a dialog for editing items. The problem starts when I try to change an item - for example I enter wider text and want all the rows in the RecyclerView to have a new width. When the dialog closes I call the function. It works, but not for all elements(?!). For example, I have 10 rows and the function stops in fourth like recyclerView.childCount only returned 4 out of 10. When I close and open Fragment all columns are again even for all elements. I tried to run the function in thread and from onLayoutCompleted:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this.context) {
    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        optimizeLayout()
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
    }
}
```

```
val runnable = Runnable {
    while (true) {
        optimizeLayout()
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

Every time with the same result. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should never reference recycled views outside of onBindViewHolder.

The reason all of the recycler views are not updating is due to the views not being drawn yet when you call `optimizeLayout()`. A RecyclerView recycles views and only draws them when they become visible.

I suggest following [google design](https://material.io/components/lists#usage) guidelines for list patterns

Which would make the view match parent or keep a consistent width across all views.

If that is not an option I would loop through the string list and find the string with the greatest length and calculate the width and pass it to the adapter before setting the adapter list.

Comment: I also tried to calculate width and pass it in OnBind but the problem was that I could not get good measure. A tried to loop throught all elements and put them in outside TextView and get width of thet TV but for some reason the width was different than the width in RecycleView. I could not find good way to measure String in pixels